# PDF Parser API in Java

Tags: java, api, pdf, parsing

I want to convert the pdf data into our own file specifications.
So pls help me out to choose the correct API for PDF parsing using java or .net. The parsing should extract each and every component(element) from the PDF pages.

Answer (score 2):

There's a library called [IText](http://itextpdf.com/) that does what you want. It's sort of the #1 product out there and is free as in beer.

I've worked with IText before, extracting content from PDFs, and while it's not super-duper automatic, it allows you to get at everything.

Recommended, in other words.

Comment: @Naimur it's in AGPL, you may want to check the license compatibility with your program.

Comment: In addition to that the PDF Reference will be required to understand the format. You can find it here (ISO charges, free links at end of page): http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

Comment: Thanks a lot carl.. Actually i started using iText only.. I want to know how to get the text which is in non readable format (some complex pdf structures). Also i need to get the type of pdf form whether it is scannable form or pre printed form or something els..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @streetpc: ... or get an older version which is "just as good" and was LGPL as far as i remember

Comment: My own work with PDF was rather simple, so I can't advise on details. I had the impression, though, that IText will allow you to get at everything if you just know how to ask. You will certainly need to understand the file structure in detail. Stroboskop's answer may help you there.

Comment: Thanks guys... If any other suggestions, help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Elements do not exist in the PDF file. It is a set of Pdfobjects which generate the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try
PDF Box  http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries/pdf-box

Hope it will help.